# Disable Required validation on some specific input fields if they are hidden with select tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

Hi guys can you help me solve this i used display:none to hide some input fields and display them with a select tag, if it's on a specific country, so when i tried submitting the form it keeps asking the hidden input field to be filled whereas they are hidden with select tag, i want this specific input field to be disable if hidden, then enable when show with required, so if input is shown enable required else disable required if input is hidden

```
<form action="d.php" method="POST">
<select id="test" name="form_select" title="Select Country" onchange="showDiv(this)" required>
   <option value="">- Select Country -</option>
   <option value="United States">United States</option>
   <option value="United kingdom">United kingdom</option>
   <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
</select><br/>
<input id="first" name="first" placeholder="first" value="" required><div>&nbsp;</div>
<input id="second" name="second" placeholder="second " value="" required><div>&nbsp;</div>
<input id="third" style="display:none;" placeholder="third" name="third" value="" required><div>&nbsp;</div>
<input id="forth" style="display:none;" placeholder="forth" name="forth" value="" required><div>&nbsp;</div>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function showDiv(select){
   if(select.value== "United States"){
    document.getElementById('third').style.display = "block";
   } else{
    document.getElementById('third').style.display = "none";
   }
   if(select.value== "United kingdom"){
    document.getElementById('forth').style.display = "block";
   } else{
    document.getElementById('forth').style.display = "none";
   }
   
} 
</script>
```

and also the space between the "second" and the "third" is what i want as the space between the "second" and the "forth" and any other fifth and six if i decided to add to the text field, i want hidden input field to be on same line

second and third
https://i.ibb.co/dQcXS2x/1.png

second and forth
https://i.ibb.co/c11VBfc/2.png

Answer (score 0):

You may set the `required` attribute for such inputs, like this:

```
if (this.value === "United States") {
  third.style.display = "block";
  third.required = true;
} else {
  third.style.display = "none";
  third.required = false;
}

if (this.value === "United kingdom") {
  forth.style.display = "block";
  forth.required = true;
} else {
  forth.style.display = "none";
  forth.required = false;
}
```

Something like this:

```js
(function() {
  var selTest = document.getElementById("test");
  var first = document.getElementById("first");
  var second = document.getElementById("second");
  var third = document.getElementById("third");
  var forth = document.getElementById("forth");

  selTest.onchange = function() {
    if (this.value === "United States") {
      third.style.display = "block";
      third.required = true;
    } else {
      third.style.display = "none";
      third.required = false;
    }

    if (this.value === "United kingdom") {
      forth.style.display = "block";
      forth.required = true;
    } else {
      forth.style.display = "none";
      forth.required = false;
    }
  };
}());
```

```html
<form action="d.php" method="POST">
  <select id="test" name="form_select" title="Select Country" onchange="showDiv(this)" required>
    <option value="">- Select Country -</option>
    <option value="United States">United States</option>
    <option value="United kingdom">United kingdom</option>
    <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
  </select><br/>
  <input id="first" name="first" placeholder="first" value="" required>
  <div>&nbsp;</div>
  <input id="second" name="second" placeholder="second " value="" required>
  <div>&nbsp;</div>
  <input id="third" style="display: none;" placeholder="third" name="third" value="" required>
  <div>&nbsp;</div>
  <input id="forth" style="display: none;" placeholder="forth" name="forth" value="" required>
  <div>&nbsp;</div>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

**Update:**

With `div` and CSS3 styles.

```js
(function() {
  var selTest = document.getElementById("test");
  var first = document.getElementById("first");
  var second = document.getElementById("second");
  var third = document.getElementById("third");
  var forth = document.getElementById("forth");

  selTest.onchange = function() {
    if (this.value === "United States") {
      third.style.display = "block";
      third.required = true;
    } else {
      third.style.display = "none";
      third.required = false;
    }

    if (this.value === "United kingdom") {
      forth.style.display = "block";
      forth.required = true;
    } else {
      forth.style.display = "none";
      forth.required = false;
    }
  };
}());
```

```css
form {
  border: #ccc solid 1px;
}

form div {
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<form action="d.php" method="POST">
  <div>
    <select id="test" name="form_select" title="Select Country" onchange="showDiv(this)" required>
      <option value="">- Select Country -</option>
      <option value="United States">United States</option>
      <option value="United kingdom">United kingdom</option>
      <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
    </select><br/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="first" name="first" placeholder="first" value="" required>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="second" name="second" placeholder="second " value="" required>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="third" style="display: none;" placeholder="third" name="third" value="" required>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="forth" style="display: none;" placeholder="forth" name="forth" value="" required>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: thank you solved that, what about the screenshot i posted i want the third and forth input field to be on the same line if i select it, the forth has more <b/> than the third see the screenshot,  
second and third https://i.ibb.co/dQcXS2x/1.png

second and forth https://i.ibb.co/c11VBfc/2.png

Comment: @SteveConder Hi, sorry for the delayed answer. I have updated my answer with a new snippet code by using `div`s and CSS3.